# When is a second derivative test considered inconclusive?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Just to check in, when a second derivative test is inconclusive does that mean $f^{'}(x)=0$ and $f^{"}(x)=0$ and there is a saddle point?

Comment: "Inconclusive" means you can't tell (just from the 2nd derivative test) whether there's a local max, a local min, or neither.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner saddle point does exist in single-variable calculus, and $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$ is a classic example.

Comment: @TravorLiu:  according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point#Mathematical_discussion), you are indeed correct

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd derivative test is inconclusive when you evaluate the 2nd derivative at your critical numbers and you get either $0$ or undefined.

NOTE: You'll only apply the 2nd derivative test when $f$ is continuous and differentiable and $c$ is a number such that $f^{'}(c)=0$ and $f^{''}$ exists near $c$

EXAMPLE: $f(x)=-3x^{5}+5x^3$ you find critical numbers: $x=-1,0,1$

We find that $f^{''}(0)=0$ so we know the second derivative test is *inconclusive*: in other words, the change in the slope is not known, so we don't know what the 'curve' will be.

We have received word that there can be a saddle point. But *I don't know* how to find that.

Comment: It was pointed out in comments above that saddle point *does* exist in single variable calculus

Comment: @J.W.Tanner my bad.